# Parsing XML commands and parameters

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, xml

I'm C# programmer and started Python recently for a new project.

This is a part of my project, and I want your opinion about my code and if it's clean or dirty, too long, has duplicate code, or it's good and standard.

(cmd= command ... at the end of file is just for class testing)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#TODO: processing attributes should be case insencitive

class command:
    def __init__ (self,htmlcommand):
        self.preview=False
        self.members=[]
        self.__parse__(htmlcommand)        



    def __parse__(self,htmlcommand):
        root = ET.fromstring(htmlcommand)
        self.service=root.attrib['service']
        self.name=root.attrib['name']
        self.source=root.attrib['source']        
        self.preview=bool(root.attrib['preview'])
        self.procedurename=root.attrib['procedurename']  

        mems=root.findall('member')
        if(len(mems)==0):
            raise Exception('command has no member')
        for m in mems:            
            self.members.append(member(m))

class member:
    def __init__ (self,member):
        self.params=[]
        self.__parse__(member)

    def __parse__(self,member):                            
        self.name=member.attrib['name']
        self.method=member.attrib['method']        
        try: 
            self.order=member.attrib['order']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.sort=member.attrib['sort']        
        except:
            pass
        self.__parseparams__(member)

    def __parseparams__(self,member):
        params=member.findall('./params/param')        
        for p in params:
            self.params.append(param(p))    

    #def __getparams(member):

class param:
    def __init__(self,param):        
        self.name=param.attrib['name']
        self.value=param.attrib['value']

cmd= command("""<basis core="external.ws.ws" service="bimepasargad" content="33,444" name="Internalissuance" source="cmsDbService" procedurename="sbserviceprocedure2" preview="true">
            <member name="bimepasargadInternalIssuance" method="internalissuance" sort="random">
                <params>
                    <param name="cms.query.token" value="111"/>
                    <param name="duration" value="2222"/>
                </params>
            </member>
            <member name="2" method="2" sort="random">
                <params>
                    <param name="cms.query.token" value="3"/>       
                </params>
            </member>
        </basis> """)
```

Comment: Could you add (an anonymized version of) the XML file so we can see whether you have a efficient way of finding what you're looking for? While you're at it, please add sufficient context as to the exact function of your program. What made you write it, what problem does it solve?

Comment: well its just a parser for specific language. I just want to know my coding style in python is good? its a command named basis and should have one or more members and each member can have 0 or more params and all param nodes should be inside params node

Comment: The conversion from string to boolean must not be done with the `bool()` function like this `self.preview=bool(root.attrib['preview'])` because any non-empty string is evaluated to True even the "false" string. You can replace by: `self.preview = root.attrib['preview']) == "true"` since the only possible values are "true" and "false".

Comment: Raising `Exception` is generally considered a bad practice. You should create a subclass of it. It is more difficult to design an exception handler when you get a exception of type `Exception`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Python naming conventions**

- `module_name`: name of a Python module = name of the file `module_name.py` without extension;
- `package_name`: name of a Python package (a directory with a `__init__.py` file) = name of the directory;
- `global_variable`/`local_variable`/`attribute_name`: name of a global variable (module-level variable), local variable (function variable), class variable (ie:  `ClassName.attribute_name`), or instance variable (ie: `self.attribute_name`)
- `A_CONSTANT`: name of a "constant" (read-only by convention), also used for class, function and instance.
- `function_name`/`method_name`: name of a function (or method);
- `ClassName`: name of a class.

In Python, there is no access restriction, everything is *public*, but we use to have the following rules:

- `_protected_name`: we add a single underscore to mark a module/package/variable/class/function/method/attribute **protected**,
- `__private_name`: we add a double underscore to mark a module/package/variable/class/function/method/attribute **private**.

**note:** Internally, Python will rename the **private** methods and attributes to make them a little harder to used from outside the class. We call that "name mangling". Consult the Python documentation: [9.6. Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden = "Me"

    def __method(self):
        print(self.hidden)

    def show(self):
        self.__method()


a = MyClass()
a.show()
# -> Me

a._MyClass__method()  # name mangling
# -> Me

a.__method()
# -> AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__method'
```

Private variables are not very popular in Python.

**Magic methods**

Magic methods, in Python, are methods which name is surrounded by double underscores ("dunder"). There are used to define operators (`__eq__`, `__add__`, ...), special methods (`__init__`, `__new__`, ...), protocols (`__enter__` / `__exit__`), etc.

There is a great article on GitHub [Magic Methods](https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods/blob/master/magicmethods.markdown) by Gabriel NIEBLER and ali.

**Code Style Review**

PEP 8 coding style violation (see the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

- No white space before '(' or after ')'
- Missing white space after ','
- missing whitespace around operator: "=", "+", "-", "/", "*", "%", etc.
- Expecting 1 blank lines between methods
- Expecting 2 blank lines between classes and functions

Also, you can fix spelling of "htmlcommand" => "html_command" for better maintenance.

Your constructor could be re-written like this:

```
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, html_command):
        self.preview = False
        self.members = []
        self._parse(html_command)
```

**Note:** If you are using Python 2.7, you should inherit the `object` class to used new style classes/object model.

**Best practices**

It is a usually (but not always) considered a best practice to define all your attributes in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, html_command):
    self.service = None
    self.name = None
    self.source = None
    self.preview = None
    self.procedure_name = None
    self.members = None
    self._parse(html_command)
```

As I told you, it's better to used your own exception class, for instance:

```
class InvalidCommandException(Exception):
    pass
```

That way, the user of your library can write it's own exception handler:

```
html_command = "..."
try:
    command = Command(html_command)
except InvalidCommandException as exc:
    print("Error: {0}".format(exc))
```

This avoid catching all `Exception`...

For that, you could define the `_parse()` method like this:

```
def _parse(self, html_command):
    root = ET.fromstring(html_command)
    self.service = root.attrib['service']
    self.name = root.attrib['name']
    self.source = root.attrib['source']
    self.preview = root.attrib['preview'] == "true"
    self.procedure_name = root.attrib['procedurename']
    members = root.findall('member')
    if not members:
        raise InvalidCommandException('command has no member')
    self.members = [Member(m) for m in members]
```

You can notice the used of a comprehension list to fill the `self.members` attribute. It generally more efficient that a loop with `append()`.

**note:** if an attribute is missing, the `KeyError` exception will be raised. If you want a different behavior an raise your own exception, you need to wrap the parse function into a exception manager:

```
    try:
        self.service = root.attrib['service']
        self.name = root.attrib['name']
        self.source = root.attrib['source']
        self.preview = root.attrib['preview'] == "true"
        self.procedure_name = root.attrib['procedurename']
    except KeyError as exc:
        raise InvalidCommandException("Missing attribute: {key}".format(key=str(exc)))
```

For `Member` class, we can simplify a lot. Since the `_parse()` method is only used in the constructor, why not use it's implementation in it?

```
class Member(object):
    def __init__(self, member):
        self.name = member.attrib['name']
        self.method = member.attrib['method']
        self.order = member.attrib.get('order')
        self.sort = member.attrib.get('sort')
        params = member.findall('./params/param')
        self.params = [Param(p) for p in params]
```

Of course, we can do that for the other classes too.

You can use `get()` to retrieve optional attributes.

**Other remarks**

I noticed that all classes except `Command` use a etree node as constructor parameter. So, I think, it's better to change the signature of the `Command` constructor to accept a etree node too:

You could also add a `__repr__` method to help debugging:

```
def __repr__(self):
    cls = self.__class__.__name__
    fmt = "{cls}(name={name!r})"
    return fmt.format(cls=cls, name=self.name)
```

**The result**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class InvalidCommandException(Exception):
    pass


class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, command):
        try:
            self.service = command.attrib['service']
            self.name = command.attrib['name']
            self.source = command.attrib['source']
            self.preview = command.attrib['preview'] == "true"
            self.procedure_name = command.attrib['procedurename']
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise InvalidCommandException("Missing attribute: {key}".format(key=str(exc)))
        members = command.findall('member')
        if not members:
            raise InvalidCommandException('Command has no member')
        self.members = [Member(m) for m in members]

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        fmt = "{cls}(name={name!r})"
        return fmt.format(cls=cls, name=self.name)


class Member(object):
    def __init__(self, member):
        try:
            self.name = member.attrib['name']
            self.method = member.attrib['method']
            self.order = member.attrib.get('order')
            self.sort = member.attrib.get('sort')
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise InvalidCommandException("Missing attribute: {key}".format(key=str(exc)))
        params = member.findall('./params/param')
        self.params = [Param(p) for p in params]

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        fmt = "{cls}(name={name!r})"
        return fmt.format(cls=cls, name=self.name)


class Param(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        try:
            self.name = param.attrib['name']
            self.value = param.attrib['value']
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise InvalidCommandException("Missing attribute: {key}".format(key=str(exc)))

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        fmt = "{cls}(name={name!r}, value={value!r})"
        return fmt.format(cls=cls, name=self.name, value=self.value)


def main():
    html_command = """\
    <basis core="external.ws.ws" service="bimepasargad"
           content="33,444" name="Internalissuance"
           source="cmsDbService" procedurename="sbserviceprocedure2"
           preview="true">
        <member name="bimepasargadInternalIssuance"
        method="internalissuance" sort="random">
            <params>
                <param name="cms.query.token" value="111"/>
                <param name="duration" value="2222"/>
            </params>
        </member>
        <member name="2" method="2" sort="random">
            <params>
                <param name="cms.query.token" value="3"/>
            </params>
        </member>
    </basis>"""
    root = ET.fromstring(html_command)

    try:
        command = Command(root)
        print(command)
        print(command.members)
        print(command.members[0].params)
    except InvalidCommandException as exc:
        print("Error: {0}".format(exc))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
Command(name='Internalissuance')
[Member(name='bimepasargadInternalIssuance'), Member(name='2')]
[Param(name='cms.query.token', value='111'), Param(name='duration', value='2222')]
```

Answer (score 6):

Multiple things to fix:

- *variable naming* - class names should be in camel-case and start with a capital letter ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)); when there are multiple words in a variable, you should put underscore between them, e.g. in your case `procedurename` would become `procedure_name`
- *missing spaces* - there should be spaces around operators, like around the `=` here:

  ```
  self.name = param.attrib['name']
  ```
- *incorrect private method naming* - when you put double underscores around a method name (this is called "dunder"), you are implying that it is a "magic method" which may confuse future readers of your code (which can also be you); while, I think you meant to create a private method. In other words, naming the method `__parse`, not `__parse__`
- `if(len(mems)==0):` can be simplified as `if not mems:`
- [bare `except` clause should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements), either replace with handling a more specific error type:

  ```
  try: 
      self.order=member.attrib['order']
  except:
      pass
  ```

  with:

  ```
  try: 
      self.order = member.attrib['order']
  except KeyError:
      pass
  ```

  Or, follow the @LaurentLAPORTE's advice and use the `.get()` method to set the `self.order` to `None` if the "order" attribute does not exist:

  ```
  self.order = member.attrib.get('order')
  ```

Comment: The OP could use `self.order = member.attrib.get('order')`. That way the _order_ attributes will be initialized with `None` if the attribute is missing instead of no initialization at all.

Comment: Note that `__parse__` is not rigorously a magic method but a private one. It looks like a magic method, so it can confuse the developer.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE you are right, the "confusing" naming is what I meant, I've improved the wording. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE IF you need private methods, call them _method() with exactly one underscore. The command class should have at least one public method that you are calling, in this case parse() might be a good name.